# Asp.net bug (Showing data during debugging in dataset but the data can not be assigned to Asp.net controls such as Gridview,TextBox,etc)

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, dataset, asp.net-controls

Asp.net Debug mode showing data in dataset but asp.net controls are not getting able to assigned the dataset's Value

Asp.net bug (Showing data during debugging in dataset but the data can not be assigned to Asp.net controls such as Gridview,TextBox,etc)

```
txtToDate.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString(); //NOT ASSIGNING VALUE TO TEXTBOX AND YES THE DATA IS PRESENT AT ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
```

I have added code in my question. Just FYI, data in Data table coming from textfile and textfile is created to local drive and coming from FTP server. But when I use textfile residing on local drive (older files) there are working fine and controls such as textbox are showing data

Comment: have u bind your dataset as datasource to asp controls?

Comment: put you html of control and dataset in your question.

Comment: @Hendra Lim I am using like this txtToDate.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();

Comment: @Shekhar I have added code in my question. Just FYI, data in Data table coming from textfile and textfile is created to local drive and coming from FTP server. But when I use textfile residing on local drive (older files) there are working fine and controls such as textbox are showing data

Answer (score 0):

Check your update panels,
your button may be in update panel and textbox may not be there.
If it does not solve your question you need to give your aspx file.